# Fedora 30, Xfce wallpaper don't change

Tags: xfce

Fedora 30, clean install from zero.
Works all but xfce4 wallpaper won't change
If I click "set as background" on image nothing happen
I try to debug with

```
xfdesktop -Q && xfdesktop -e > /tmp/xf.log 2>&1
```

But the log report nothing strange
If I try to change from dekstop menu

[image]

as you can see is impossible to select any image.
With this folder and with any folder with images.
I tried also disabling selinux, nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: a workaround
I go in this folder

```
cd /usr/share/backgrounds/images
```

Then with ln -s I put my backgrounds from other folders
For example

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/backgrounds/f25/extras/* .
```

Then I can select my background without problem.